# How to remove default "Error" from main Result handler

Tags: error-handling, rust, program-entry-point, boilerplate

I'm trying to make my own custom errors, yet I do not want Rust to automatically add `Error:`  in front of the error messages. How would I do this?

Code:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum CustomError {
    Test
}
impl fmt::Display for CustomError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            CustomError::Test => write!(f, "Test")
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), CustomError> {
    Err(CustomError::Test)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

**Expected** Output (stderr):

> `Test`

**Actual** Output (stderr):

> `Error: Test`

Comment: In this case process will exit with an error code, you might consider handling error inside main instead of propagate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, can you clarify? I am indeed testing the process by forcing an error code through Result<(), CustomError>.

Comment: I was thinking something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73bd5bfd30b46b5dfef600d90d6418ca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Error:` prefix is added by the [`Termination` implementation for `Result`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e8b55a4ad230ebec762fdfc4f241ba98a98560af/src/libstd/process.rs#L1689-L1696). Your easiest option to avoid it is to make `main()` return `()` instead, and then handle the errors yourself in `main()`. Example:

```
fn foo() -> Result<(), CustomError> {
    Err(CustomError::Test)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = foo() {
        eprintln!("{:?}", e);
    }
}
```

If you are fine using unstable features, you can also

- implement the `Termination` and `Try` traits on a custom result type, which would allow you to use your original code in `main()`, but customize its behaviour. (For this simple case, this seems overkill to me.)
- return an `ExitCode` from main, which allows you to indicate `ExitCode::SUCCESS` or `ExitCode::FAILURE`. You can also set an exit code using `std::process::exit()`, but I'm not aware of a way of accessing the platform-dependent success and failure codes in stable Rust.

Comment: Thank's for the heads up! I also looked into this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1176#issuecomment-115975651 (which also shows a similar answer). Keeping this here for other people in case they need it! ;)